# Android - get frames from MediaPlayer playing on SurfaceView to pass them to Native C++ code

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, android-mediaplayer

As the title describe, I'm trying to get `MediaPlayer` frames (while playing) and pass them to my C++ native code (using `JNI`).

So, I use `MediaPlayer` and "`setDisplay(SurfaceView)`" method to draw video pixels on the `SurfaceView`.

During the video playback, I use the "`getDrawingCache`" method of the `SurfaceView` to get last video frame pixels. But i've read that it the Bitmap will always be black.

So my question is : Is it possible to get the last frame displayed by `MediaPlayer`, in order to pass it to C++ code ?

PS : I have to use API level 8

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Android 4.1 they added a MediaCodec Api that allows you to access pretty much everything.

And in Android 4.3 they added the possibility to get the stream from a Surface.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html

Before that, you are pretty much stuck. You can try to use the ffmpeg + JNI via NDK solution.
It seems pretty hard to accomplish but the good news is if you make it, your frames will already be read at the C++ level.

Comment: Thanks, but in fact, i have to use api level 8 (i'll edit my question)

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not for API level 8, but for API level 19+, you could get the surface from the surface view, and pass it to [ImageReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader).

> The ImageReader class allows direct application access to image data rendered into a Surface

You can set a listener on the ImageReader using `setOnImageAvailableListener`. This will get you all the frames, including the last one.